# filter tablix without datasource values in ssrs

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

I have SSRS report and I need to filter a static table that I created inside the report based on parameter. There is no data source to this table and I'm entering the data manually.
The tablix contain 3 columns.
How can I filter the columns based on parameter?
I tried in the expression =@param1 for example but it doesn't work.
For now I only manage to filter if the expression is on data source fields.

Answer (score 1):

Do you literally have a table with a number of values in it written directly into the report?  If so I don't think you will be able to perform any filtering on it as effectively all you've done it write data into textboxes that are displayed.

I would imagine your best option would be to instead create a new dataset and populate this with your static data, e.g.

```
SELECT 'A' AS Letter, 'English' AS Language
UNION
SELECT 'B' AS Letter, 'French' AS Language
UNION
SELECT 'A' AS Letter, 'German' AS Language
```

To give you a table as follows

```
Letter |  Language
-------+----------
A      |  English
B      |  French
A      |  German
```

That you could then filter on `Letter = A`

Answer (score 0):

So essentially you have a Tablix that has 3 columns pre-populated with information you have manually entered into the text boxes themselves? Since you've already entered that data, I don't believe there is a way to filter that at run time. That data is hard coded in essence. The Filter ability in SSRS is used as a `WHERE` clause so it restricts what is brought forth into the report from the query.

I would create a data source connection to a dummy database, create a DataSet, and create a query that fills a temporary table will all the information that you've manually entered. Once you create the temporary table and inserted values into it, you can then perform a `SELECT` with a parameter. Your Tablix will only be populated with information that matches the parameter. Something to the effect of this:

```
CREATE TABLE #TempTable (
    ID INT
    ,Name VARCHAR(MAX)
    ,Email VARCHAR(MAX)
    )

INSERT INTO #TempTable (
    ID
    ,Name
    ,Email
    )
VALUES (
    1
    ,'Bob'
    ,'bob@email.com'
    )
    ,(
    2
    ,'Frank'
    ,'frank@email.com'
    )
    ,(
    3
    ,'Jim'
    ,'jim@email.com'
    )
SELECT
    *
FROM
    #TempTable
WHERE
    ID = @ID
DROP TABLE #TempTable
```